# Xunit - How to mock HTTP POST request - ControllerBase.Request is null when trying to mock

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, xunit.net

I am trying to write a test case in xunit for post method. I am getting NullreferenceException when trying to mock Post request in httpClient. In Post method body, I need to pass a file, but when I tried to add data to body, I am getting error as in image. Can anyone tell me how to write xunit test case to handle this error.

[image: Exception]

Comment: Need more details - and code snippet if possible.

Comment: @Anuraj, Hi In this code snipped, there is a post method in controller to add files and it is working file. In postman, we are adding files in body, but when I am trying to add test case for this controller, request.body is coming as null. I tried to mock like  below code in test case and call controller after that, but still request body is not filling    using var tarStream = new MemoryStream(new byte[2] { 2, 4 });
            var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
            await httpContext.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(tarStream);